# Remove taxonomy page navigation pages

Tags: 6

I've a taxonomy [page of a company](http://bit.do/edt74) which should show all nodes pages with this term.

I want that this page list at least 20 or so nodes, then we will need to click 1 or 2 or 3 to go to next levels.

Currently you can see every page is listing only single node. How to change this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your view is setup to show 1 node per page.

> 1. Go into views `admin/build/views`
> 2. Choose the view that is used for those pages most probably `taxonomy_term` view
> 3. On `basic settings: use pager` click on the cogwheel and change the items from 1 to 20 items per page
> 4. After saving this setting the basic setting should look like the following image

[image]

Comment: taxonomy_term view is disabled in the website

Comment: you can probably enable it and override the display but I would do this in a testing environment ... it might be a contrib module that is handling the taxonomy term page display ... you can list the names of the other views it might help to pinpoint which one is used or give us a list of modules enabled ... you probably have 1 of the following modules enabled TVI, taxonomypageoverride, taxonomy_display, taxonomy_pages that override how taxonomy pages are used/displayed